# Put two or more values to one input (number field)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, node.js

I have an number type input field...

I want this format:

**Age-Height-Weight**

**20-180-80**

How can I force users input exactly this type and then insert the final result to the input field type="number" and submit it?

Age — from 16 to 99
Height — from 100 to 290
Weight — from 40 to 200

Then the result, for example 18-170-60 must be sent as one value...

Comment: As its name indicates, an input of `type="number"` can only have a number as a value. What you describe here is an input of type `text` to which you want to apply validation

Comment: 20-180-80 this is text not number. So you can't do it with number input

Comment: Okay, how can I do it text field?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this basically like this. Use pattern for a basic validation and validate for an additional validation. It's not perfect (and free of bugs) yet, but it should give you a good direction.

```js
let input = document.querySelector("#age-height-weight");

function validate() {
  let regex = /(\d+)-(\d+)-(\d+)/
  let content = regex.exec(input.value);
  input.setCustomValidity("");
  
  // This validation is done implicitly using 'pattern' and 'required', 
  // but you could also do this manually, which would be actually more consistent.
  if (!content) return;
  
  // Now the additonal validation, if the pattern basically is fine.
  let [all, age, height, weight] = content;
  if (age < 16 || age > 99) {
    input.setCustomValidity("Invalid age.")
  }
  if (height < 100 || height > 290) {
    input.setCustomValidity("Invalid height.")
  }
  if (weight < 40 || weight > 200) {
    input.setCustomValidity("Invalid weight.")
  }
}

input.addEventListener("focusout", validate);
input.addEventListener("focusin", validate);
```

```html
<form id="my-form">
  <input type="text" id="age-height-weight" pattern="\d{2}-\d{3}-\d{2,3}" title="Age (16-99)-Height (100-290)-Weight (40-200)" required>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this by using the telephone html input instead by using some regex to get the format you want. Here is a snippet of the solution

**Note: The pattern tag isn't supported in Safari 10 or earlier, to support that you'll want the regex to be done through javascript**

```js
var sub = document.getElementById("submit");
var input = document.getElementById("userinfo");
sub.onsubmit = function() {
 var args = input.value.split("-");
    if (args[0] < 16 || args[0] > 99) { invalidInput("age"); return; } 
    if (args[1] < 100 || args[1] > 290) { invalidInput("height"); return; }
    if (args[2] < 40 || args[2] > 200) { invalidInput("weight"); return; }
    console.log(`Age: ${args[0]}, Height: ${args[1]}, Weight: ${args[2]}`);
}
function invalidInput(type) {
    console.log(`Input "${type}" was invalid`);
    return;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="submit">
  <label for="userinfo">Info:</label>
  <input type="text" id="userinfo" placeholder="Age-Weight-Height" pattern="[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{2,3}" title="Three, Three digit numbers, separated by hyphons e.g. 123-123-123"><br><br>
  <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>

</html>
```